# Swig (node.js) Include a File and pass an object

Tags: node.js, swig-template

I am facing this problem.

I've got a page with an include of another like this:

index.html

```
{{ set pets = { pets : petsObject } }}
{{ include pets.html }}
```

petsObject is an object like this

```
petsObjects: [
{ name : "cat" },
{ name : "dog" }
]
```

When I try to render the page I get a blank page with only this:

[object Object]

I have no clue about what is going on :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We definitely need to see the contents of 'pets.html' as well. But, also, that should be a tag with a string (typo?): `{% include "pets.html" %}`

Comment: I Use a hidden text area, and fill up with `JSON.stringify(object)`... then in JS after `$(document).ready()`  read the value an do `JSON.parse($('.hiddentextarea').val());`

Answer (score 9):

Seems you'll need to use:

```
{% include pets.html with pets %}
```

According to [docs for `include`](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/#include):

> Locally declared context variables are *not* passed to the included template by default.

It is also recommended for performance to use the `only` keyword after the included terms, like this:

```
{% include pets.html with pets only %}
```

Beyond that, it depends on the contents of `pets.html`, which you haven't included here. But, make sure that you're attempting to output the `name`:

```
{% for pet in pets %}
  {{ pet.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or use a filter like [`json_encode()`](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/#filters-json_encode) to format it:

```
{% for pet in pets %}
  {{ pet|json_encode }}
{% endfor %}
```

Trying to output the `Object`s themselves will [simply produce `[object Object]`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2):

```
new Object().toString() === "[object Object]"
```